# How can I change the source of background image in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is how i set the background:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<AppInterface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            id: backg # im not sure if i can set an id for this
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'assets/background.jpg'
#rest of the code goes here
''')
```

and then later i want to change the source of the image, when the user presses the button, but I don't know how to do that. I tried a few stuff like

```
self.ids.backg.source = 'assets/background2.jpg'
```

but this didn't work. I am using FloatLayout. Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referancing by `StringProperty()`

.py side, in `AppInterface` class:

```
background_source = StringProperty('assets/background.jpg')
```

.kv side:

```
source: root.background_source
```

Now, if you want to change that image, just set new path like: (in .py side)

```
background_source = 'assets/background2.jpg'
```